# http.Server — get URL fragment

Tags: go

Have no luck with extracting fragment data (`foo` in http://domain.com/path#foo) with standard `http.Server`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type Handler struct {
}

func (handler Handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("Path = \"%v\"  Fragment = \"%v\"\n", r.URL.Path, r.URL.Fragment)
}

func main() {
    var handler Handler
    http.ListenAndServe(":30000", handler)
}
```

produces empty fragment for `http://127.0.0.1:30000/path#foo`:

`Path = "/path"  Fragment = ""`

How can I get fragment data using golang's builtin `http.Server`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't. This isn't a Go thing -- URL fragments are not sent to the server over HTTP. They're just a browser concept.

Here is [a relevant issue](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3805), where [the docs for `http.Request`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) were changed to say:

```
// For server requests the URL is parsed from the URI
// supplied on the Request-Line as stored in RequestURI.  For
// most requests, fields other than Path and RawQuery will be
// empty. (See RFC 2616, Section 5.1.2)
```

If for some reason you need it, you could probably string together some JavaScript to include the fragment in the request as a `GET` parameter or something.